# I want to create a custom GROK for my log

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, opensearch

log example:

```
30-10-22 20:35:36       [DEBUG] [Default]       [Worker]         Sleeping for 10 seconds...
```

I can get `%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}` or `%{LOGLEVEL:log-level}`
but I need only the message "`Sleeping for 10 seconds...`"

`%{GREEDYDATA:message}` return all the message:

```
Sleeping for 10 seconds...
```

Example from opensearch output:

```
@timestamp
Nov 2, 2022 @ 12:30:45.074
    
@version
1
    
_id
Z_nkN4QBewLz0DWJsjKB
    
_index
logstash-logs-2022.11.02
    
_score
 - 
    
_type
_doc
    
host
ip-10-155-29-101
    
log-level_pvt
DEBUG
    
message
30-10-22 19:58:28   [DEBUG] [Default]   [Worker]     Sleeping for 10 seconds...
    
message_pvt
30-10-22 19:58:28   [DEBUG] [Default]   [Worker]     Sleeping for 10 seconds...
    
path
/home/ubuntu/logstashdir/WorkerLogs/EC2AMAZ-06N2AJA_2.log
    
timestamp_pvt
30-10-22 19:58:28
```

in json format:

```
{
  "_index": "logstash-logs-2022.11.02",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "Z_nkN4QBewLz0DWJsjKB",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "@version": "1",
    "timestamp_pvt": "30-10-22 19:58:28",
    "message_pvt": "30-10-22 19:58:28\t[DEBUG]\t[Default]\t[Worker]\t Sleeping for 10 seconds... is 113\r",
    "@timestamp": "2022-11-02T10:30:45.074Z",
    "host": "ip-10-155-29-101",
    "path": "/home/ubuntu/logstashdir/WorkerLogs/EC2AMAZ-06N2AJA_2.log",
    "log-level_pvt": "DEBUG",
    "message": "30-10-22 19:58:28\t[DEBUG]\t[Default]\t[Worker]\t Sleeping for 10 seconds... 113\r"
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      "2022-11-02T10:30:45.074Z"
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1667385045074
  ]
}
```

Any advice?

```
filter
{
        grok
        {
                match => { "message" => "%{LOGLEVEL:log-level_pvt}" }
        }

        grok
        {
                match => { "message" => "%{GREEDYDATA:message_pvt}" }
        }
        
        grok
        {
                match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp_pvt}" }
        }
}
```

message is:

```
30-10-22 19:58:28   [DEBUG] [Default]   [Worker]     Sleeping for 10 seconds...
```

I want that message to be:

```
Sleeping for 10 seconds...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the overwrite parameter to overwrite the original message.
For performance reasons combine the grok statements and start with ^

```
grok {
    overwrite => "message"
    match => { "message" => "^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp_pvt}\t\[%{LOGLEVEL:log-level_pvt}\]\t\[%{WORD}\]\t\[%{WORD}\]%{GREEDYDATA:message}$" }
}
```